# How to genererate debian packages in play framework 1.2.x?

Tags: java, playframework

In Play Framework 2.3.x you have the native-packager as shown [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionDist). Which is a sbt plugin that provides you with everything you need to package your application. No matter if you want to build a simple standalone application or a server application. The JVM let's you run anywhere. SBT Native Packager let's you deploy everywhere.

For example as in the play documentation show you can build a debian package like this:

you have to add this to your build.sbt

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import NativePackagerKeys._

maintainer in Linux := "First Lastname <first.last@example.com>"

packageSummary in Linux := "My custom package summary"

packageDescription := "My longer package description"
```

and then you can type in the activator console:

```
activator debian:packageBin
```

before that you have to add Add the plugin to your plugins.sbt. If you use sbt 0.13.5 or higher the you have just one line to add to your build.sbt:

```
enablePlugins(SbtNativePackager)
```

This is a posible begin, but in play 1.2.x, I do not know how to begin with it. A maven plugin?. Any Idea will be nice.